# Where did Nano get money from?

Tags: nichijou

For example, for shopping.

The anime doesn't show that Prof. or Nano works. 
Does Prof. and/or Nano have a stable income?

Comment: maybe prof gets research funding

Comment: Hakase is more of a mystery than Ika Musume! Maybe she turned herself into a kid and live off royalties from her previous inventions.

Comment: perhaps she has a rich family? There's no sign for her parent anyway

Comment: I find the implication that a character in an anime like *Nichijou* need follow common sense real-world rules rather amusing.

Comment: @Jan FYI, the anime is tagged as a 'Slice Of Life', so the common sense of reality is expected.

Comment: The thing about 'Slice of Life' (a genre which I love, btway) is that it need not have anything to do with life as we know it. Common sense of reality is most certainly *not* expected. Or how do you explain a robot with a key sticking out of her back in reality's common sense?

Answer (score 2):

The money seems to be handled by Nano, so I doubt Hakase sells her inventions herself. (otherwise she would just buy **loads** of chocolate sharks)

It is presumably from a relative, or the money comes from a patent on an invention (with the money going to Nano).

No relatives are ever mentioned, so it's probably some form of research funding. (I personally think one of Hakase's inventions actually backfired at some point, turning her into a child, that would explain why she gets it and that Nano handles it.)